# Expected weight of a sub-graph

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, graph-theory

Given a complete weighted graph with a known distributions of edge weights, what is the expected distribution of the sum of the weights in randomly selected sub-cliques as a function of clique size?

(Apologies if this is a well know problem. If it is, then it's in an intersection of fields I've not worked in and thus don't know what terms to search for.)

---

Naively, the median should grow as $O(n^2)$, but I'm not seeing how to map the input distribution function to the output function. That output function (i.e. a CDF) is what I really need.

In the specific motivating case I will have the full list of weights, but it's likely to be something like $10^4$ to $10^6$ edges, so brute forcing all possible cliques, or even a non-trivial fraction of them, is likely not a viable solution.

---

The motivation for the question is an idea for a way to do [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and maybe some [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning). In short I'm looking for a way to get a comparison of how "un-random" given partitions are given only a quantitative measure of "association" between pairs of elements in the set to be partitioned.

(If this particular area is well studied and documented, I'd be interested in references to prior work. If there aren't text-book solutions to this, just playing around with things is a significant part of my goal here.)

Comment: Isn't the weight of a $k$-vertex clique just the sum of $\binom k2$ independent samples from the edge weight distribution? I don't see how the graph theory comes in.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Graph theory is in the application. The point is dealing with non random structure in the edges, which I expect will be less trivial. -- Is there a proper term for the problem as you described it? The first few things I searched came up with a bunch of stuff that wasn't applicable to that formulation.

Comment: Where is the non-random structure in the edges? As I understood the problem, the graph is complete (so all the edges are there) and the edge weights are randomly chosen from a known distribution. I am misunderstanding something, but I don't know what.

Comment: @MisgaLavrov The edge weights are not random. The final problem is to figure out in what way they are non random. I'm expecting that if AB and BC both have large weights then AC is likely to as well. And similarly for longer loops. The extreme would be if weights are 1 for "in the same partition" and 0 if not.